# On clicking on close button of page i want to clear all selectbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have 3 selectbox on my page and onClick of close button I want to clear all the selectbox which are under the class `.popup`.

Below is my code to clear fields.

```
clearText: function() {
    $('.popupBody input').val('');
    $('.popupBody select').val('');
    $('.popupForm').find('.errmsgActive').removeClass('errmsgActive');
    $('.popupForm').find('.errmsg').html('');
}
```

For clearing all select boxes inside `.popupBody` class, I am using below code.

```
 $('.popupBody select').val('');
```

Comment: Put your HTML stuff

Comment: by clearing a select i hope you mean returning the select to the default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clearing selection made in `select2` select box you can try following approach:

```
$('.popupBody select').each(function(){
    //iterate over all the select boxes one by one
    $(this).select2("val", ""); //clearing the selection made
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looks good.. obviously `$('.popupBody select').val('');` is clearing value of select dropdown under `.popupBody`.

BUT

Make sure, all select input must have option `value=''`.

#### See below code

```js
$(".popupBody select").select2();
$("#clear").click(function(){
$('.popupBody select').val('-1').change();
})
```

```css
@import "https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="popupBody">
<select>
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B1">B1</option>
<option value="C1">C1</option>
</select>

<select>
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="A2">A2</option>
<option value="B2">B2</option>
<option value="C2">C2</option>
</select>
</div>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Actually i am using selectTo plugin.

Comment: @Kalashir `selectTo` OR `select2` plugin? Please confirm.

Comment: I am using selectTo plugin , and defalut option have value = "-1"

Comment: I have tried this
$('.popupBody select').find('option:first-child').attr('selected','selected');
This is seting value to default but select box is not getting cleared.

Comment: can you please update your question and put the URL for this `selectTo` plugin homepage? I googled it but unfortunately haven't came across any plugin with name `selectTo`.

Comment: Sorry its select 2 jquery plugin

Comment: @Kalashir, I have made changes for Select2 plugin, sorry my answer was late, it you like answer then upvote or mark as correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

To reset a dropdown you need to select the default element usually the first one:

```
 $('.popupBody select').find('option:first-child').attr('selected','selected');
```

to reset the value in select2 use

```
$('.popupBody select').select2("val", "");
```

Comment: I have tried this $('.popupBody select').find('option:first-child').attr('selected','selecte‌​d'); This is setting value to default but select box is not getting cleared.

Comment: Select box is set with default value  but still showing selected country.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="popupBody">
 <label>Select option one</label>
 <select>
  <option value="">-- select --</option>
  <option>select1 value 1</option>
  <option>select1 value 2</option>
  <option>select1 value 3</option>
 </select>
 <br><br><br>

 <label>Select option two</label>
 <select>
  <option value="">-- select --</option>
  <option>select2 value 1</option>
  <option>select2 value 2</option>
  <option>select2 value 3</option>
 </select>
 <br><br><br>

 <label>Select option Three</label>
 <select>
  <option value="">-- select --</option>
  <option>Stackoverflow</option>
  <option>is</option>
  <option>awesome</option>
 </select>
 <br><br><br>
 <input type="button" name="" value="CLEAR" id="closebutton">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#closebutton").click(function(){
   $("div.popupBody select").val("");
  });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```